# Is it possible to play Minecraft with ocean water turned off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is it possible to play Minecraft without any water in ocean biomes?

Comment: It's not clear: are you aiming to eliminate ocean biomes entirely, or are you wanting ocean biomes to generate but be "dry" with no water (which I can imagine would be pretty cool, and very post-apocalypse feeling)?

Comment: I'd like them to still generate, yes.

Comment: @Suunnn I'm afraid it's still not clear what you're looking for. Do you just not want squids?

Comment: Your title says "no water in ocean biomes", your question body says "no water spawns" which rather sounds like "no squids" as @RavenDreamer suggests - so, which one is it?

Comment: @Joe I think Suunnn should clarify this, since the original question body can also be understood as "How to get rid of squids"

Comment: @Zommuter Occam's razor says that the title and body match because the OP means literally no spawning of water blocks.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie +1 for bringing [Science](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) into it :-D

Comment: I meant no water spawns in ocean biomes, ancient plateau style.  I don't care about squid.

Comment: @Suunnn You're just going to keep confusing people talking like that. In minecraft "water spawns" mean *squid*. Only creatures "spawn" in minecraft; blocks are "generated".

Comment: Well then, water blocks in ocean biomes, and the removing thereof.

Answer (score 2):

You can always install [Singleplayer Commands](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-125-single-player-commands-v322-official-download/#entry1464349), if that's still up-to-date, and use the `//drain` command with a huge radius.

Comment: what drain command, be more clear, as I've never heard of this option and I'm sure I'm not the only one.

Comment: Is this really part of SPC? It is not mentioned [here](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/94310-125-single-player-commands-v322-official-download/#commandlist) - you need [WorldEdit](http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldEdit/Utilities#Draining_pools), it's named `//drain`. (@Ender too FYI). Also note that **this will not empty the entire ocean**, and it might kill Minecraft if your radius is too large - either a lot of chunks get generated or only the existing ones are drained, I didn't check. Anyway, at some point there will be a wall of water waiting for you to trigger it's propagation...

Comment: @Zommuter it is part of WorldEdit which is bundled with SPC.

Comment: @Joe thanks for telling, that explains why WorldEdit commands are listed there :-7

Comment: This will also drain rivers, right? I don't think the OP is looking for that.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I think the OP left a drive-by question and will never clarify... `//drain` will eliminate any water blocks connected to the one below you within a certain radius. So it will dry nearby rivers connected to your ocean, but leave the ocean further away intact. It is a solution, but it involves too much manual work for my taste...

Comment: I must agree with @Zommuter, it's a solution, but only if a better one cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

**edit** To obtain "oceans" without water, I think [Terrain Control](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/terrain-control/) offers what you're looking for, and much more:

There's both a bukkit and a SSP version, and even better, if it doesn't achieve what you want, the source is hosted at [github](https://github.com/Wickth/TerrainControl), so you can simply modify it!

---

If you want to get rid of the *water* in oceans: [Mystcraft](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/918541-125-mystcraft-09102/#entry11683085) allows you to create different worlds, maybe if you create one without [water symbols](http://mystcraft.wikia.com/wiki/Symbols) you get what you want, you can e.g. use Desert or Frozen Ozeans/Rivers.

If you want to get rid of squids instead, the only thing I know about are the [bukkit](http://www.bukkit.org) plugins [NoSpawn](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/nospawn/) and [EntitySupressor](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/entitysuppressor/), i.e. you'd have to run a bukkit server for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla Minecraft, there's no setting to generate the ocean dry.

There are flat worlds that don't have oceans, but I doubt that is what you are looking for.

I know of no mods that do this either.